# can't display chinese character in the web

Tags: html

I try to implement the following code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
  <head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<title>下载</title>
     </head>
 <body>
<img src="photo1.jpg" style="width:100px; float:left;height:100px;margin-    bottom:20px;"><img src="photo2.jpg" style="float:left;margin-   left:30px;width:100px;height:100px;"><img src="photo3.jpg" style="float:left;margin-  left:30px;width:100px;height:100px;"><img src="photo4.jpg" style="float:left;margin-  left:30px;width:100px;height:100px;">
 <a href="watermark.php?src=photo1.jpg&download=true"    style="clear:both;float:left;margin-left:10px;">下载 1</a><a href="watermark.php?  src=photo2.jpg&download=true" style="float:left;margin-left:60px;">下载 2</a>
 <a href="watermark.php?src=photo3.jpg&download=true" style="float:left;margin-  left:55px;">下载 3</a><a href="watermark.php?src=photo4.jpg&download=true"    style="float:left;margin-left:50px;">下载 4</a>


  </body>
  </html>
```

I did use

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

but in the webpage it still show the litte question marks like this ??

Comment: Which browser? Which web server? Which tool did you use to edit the text?

Comment: Does it show correctly when selecting UTF-8 from the browser's View > Encoding menu?

Comment: I used ie8, the web server is verified for displaying chinese, editor I used coffee cup html editor, I couldn't find encoding menu in my editor

Comment: This has nothing to do with php.

Comment: By the way, you might want to change `<html lang="en">` to the primary language of your document.

Comment: @vsync i did this as well, and I saved the file first and then encode, but still display ???? please help me, is it necessary to use notepad ++ when editting other languages? thanks a lot!

Comment: no, you can use any other editor that supports changing the document encoding. where does it show "???" ? is in in Notepad++ or in your web browser?

Comment: no, in notepad++ it shows the chinese, but in my ie8 broswer it shows this:���� 1

Comment: just writing `<meta charset="UTF-8">` is enough in HTML5. I have checked your document and it works fine if you FIRST encode the file in UTF-8 an THEN put the text there.

Comment: @vsync, i show you what I did:  I opened the notepad++, then I copyed my code from old editor(all english no chinese) to new file, then choose utf-8 without BOM, then choose chinese GB2312(simplified), then it automatically comes up a winodw ask me to save the file, then I save the file, after that, I change the english to chinese, so what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @vsync  could you help me, thanks a lot, this is really important to me

Comment: @smith - what I did is crate a new file with notepad++, then change it's encoding to `UTF-8 without BOM`, then copy the HTML code you wrote here to that file, save everything, and drag it to the browser. works -> I see chinese.

Comment: @vsync  hah, thanks, finally, this took me ages, net step is to insert the chinese to database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure your FILE is encoded in `Big5`, and not in ANSI or anything else.
you can do that with notepad++ under the encoding menu.

[image]

Comment: If you're going for a multi-byte encoding anyway, go for UTF-8 or UTF-16, not-yet-another-subset-encoding like BIG5.

Comment: better to use UTF8 without BOM, it's recommended. you can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8

Comment: @vsync I tried exactly you showed me on notepad++, but it shows me ���� 1 ���� 2 ���� 3 ���� 4, why? thanks a lot

Comment: maybe you already SAVED the file in another encoding, which screwed all the characters. you have to FIRST make sure the document is saved in the right encoding, and only then put the text in it.